# Can I test do-release-upgrade in a chroot? Complains about EFI directory

Tags: do-release-upgrade

If I take a snapshot from my root filesystem (so an identical copy), mount it, chroot into it, and try to upgrade it using do-release-upgrade, the process fails. I have seen for example it's complaining about /boot/efi not being mounted, but of course I don't want it to mess with that (yet).

Any ideas? I am thinking about this to stage upgrades at home for remote family members, could save me a lot of time when a new LTS comes along.

Comment: Have you considered doing a full image using e. g. clonezilla and then converting it to a vbox image using `VboxManage convertfromraw --format VDI source.img target.vdi`? Never tried myself.

Comment: Yeah the thought crossed my mind. I have the snapshots available, so I could just throw those into a VM. Chroot seems so simple though.